# Tera Data what the manifest json file for ? the purpose of it?

Tags: teradata

I have a sql command below， I don't understand what the flowdata_manifest.json for.

```
SELECT NodeId, AmpId, Sequence, ObjectName, ObjectSize, RecordCount
FROM WRITE_NOS_FM (
 ON  ( SELECT * FROM RiverFlowPerm )
  PARTITION BY SiteNo ORDER BY SiteNo
 USING
  LOCATION('YOUR-STORAGE-ACCOUNT/RiverFlowPerm_PartitionBy/')
  STOREDAS('PARQUET')
  NAMING('DISCRETE')
  MANIFESTFILE('YOUR-STORAGE-ACCOUNT/RiverFlowPerm_PartitionBy/flowdata_manifest.json')
  INCLUDE_ORDERING('TRUE')
  MAXOBJECTSIZE('4MB')
  COMPRESSION('GZIP')
) AS d 
ORDER BY AmpId;
```

Comment: Look at the *Getting Started Guide* https://docs.teradata.com/r/UvoBsZYTAWt2z0jnQFJbvw/8DhBnyq3EJP5gISSP1r~zA

Comment: It  doesn't  explain  WHY  I  need this  look like useless file .  It just show me command. I need know why I need  this file ?

Comment: LOCATION('YOUR-STORAGE-ACCOUNT/20180701/ManifestFile/') <- this address path
  
MANIFESTFILE('YOUR-STORAGE-ACCOUNT/20180701/ManifestFile/manifest1.json') ???  why need another file look like  address path?

Comment: *The manifest file lists the paths of the objects stored on external object store.* This simplifies metadata access.

Comment: SO  it looks like a log file , record the write object files path ?  this manifest1.json  file is auto  modified by s3 storage? or control by  tera data?

Comment: The optional MANIFESTFILE just allows you to create a list of specific object names, versus using a generic pattern for generating / referencing names within the LOCATION.

Comment: Dear Fred,  Can you give some small  example code  of  your  answer. Let  me more easy to understand it.